# Android Navigation Drawer little "bug"

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm very, VERY new in android. So, I started with a simple application, created on min API 14, I personalized some strings and I started to modify the application drawer.

When I tried to debug my simple app and launch it on my Nexus 5 (updated to last stock lollipop), I have this little annoying bug, with this icons:

[image: Menu is closed]
[image: Menu is opened]

In all cases, when the navigation drawer is opened/closed it shows that ARROW, instead of changing between the "menu" icon and "arrow" icon.
What I'm doing wrong?

Searching for a solution, I found some lines in code, like this:

[image: restoreActionBar]
[image: MainActivity]

I don't know how to do... If you could explain me what's wrong, I'll be very happy.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `syncState()` call of your ActionBarDrawerToggle object from `onPostCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

Comment: When I try to put it into the NavigationDrawerFragment it says in the row

"super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);" that it cannot resolve this method.

Comment: I have another method:

 @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

and I tried to put it there, but it's not working.

Comment: @Martinocom you need to put this in the root `Activity` that the drawer is defined

Comment: The drawer is defined in the "NavigationDrawerFragment", but when I add it there it gets an error on "super.onPostCreate", saying he can't resolve this method

Comment: ...and exploring the code of "NavigationDrawerFragment" I could find this piece of code: <<// Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });>>